# How to convert a key string back into a pycrypto key object? (Python)

Tags: python, string, client-server, pycrypto

I am replicating a TCP client-server secure handshake in python using the pycrypto module. When the "server" sends the public key over the socket, I am forced to convert the public key to a string. The "client" then receives the public key as a string, which cannot be encrypted according the `pycrypto` module.

I get the error:

> **AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'encrypt'** in reference to **enc_data = public_key.encrypt(secret_piece, 12)** on the client side.

How do convert the string `public_key` back to its original value when it was first generated by the RSA module?

**Server Code:**

```
def main():
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 5000

s = socket.socket()
s.bind((host,port))

s.listen(1)
c, addr = s.accept()
print "Connection from: "+str(addr)
while True:
    data = c.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    print "from connected user: "+str(data)

    print "Start the SSL Handshake..."
    a = raw_input('Press enter to generate the key pair. ')

    key = RSA.generate(1024, random_generator)
    public_key = key.publickey()

    print "Key pair generated"
    a = raw_input('Press enter to send public key to client ')

    print "Sending key..."

    if c.send(str(public_key)):
        print "Public Key Sent"

    print "Waiting for secret list..."

    if c.recv(1024):
        print "List received."

    secret_list = c.recv(1024)

    a = raw_input('Press enter to check the information from the list. ')

    decrypted_info = key.decrypt(secret_list.enc_data)

    match_or_not = SHA256.new(decrypted_info).digest() == secret_list.hash_value

    if match_or_not:
        print "Info Matches. Sending the ciphertext..."

    info_to_be_encrypted = "It seems all secure. Let's talk!"
    aes = AES.new(Random.get_random_bytes(16), AES.MODE_ECB)
    cipher_text = aes.encrypt(info_to_be_encrypted)

    if c.send(cipher_text):
        print "Ciphertext sent."
```

**Client Code**

```
def main():
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 5000

s = socket.socket()
s.connect((host,port))



message = raw_input("-> ")
while message != 'q':
    s.send(message)
    public_key = s.recv(1024)
    print 'Received from server: '+str(public_key)

    message = raw_input("->Press enter to verify the public key.")
    print "Public Key verified!"
    message = raw_input("-> Press enter to prepare the secret list.")
    print "Client prepares the secret list."

    secret_piece = Random.get_random_bytes(16)
    enc_data = public_key.encrypt(secret_piece, 12)
    hash_value = SHA256.new(secret_piece).digest()
    L = [enc_data, hash_value]

    print "List is ready."
    message = raw_input("-> Press enter to send the list")

    s.send(str(L))
    print "List sent."
    print "Waiting for ciphertext from the server..."

    if s.recv(1024):
        print "Ciphertext recieved."

    cipher_text = s.recv(1024)

    print "The encrypted message is: " + cipher_text
    print "The decrypted message is: " + aes.decrypt(cipher_text)




s.close()
```

Comment: 1. Why are you "forced to convert the public key to a string"? 2. If you must just reverse the encoding. 3. Perhaps you are confusing a sequence of binary bytes with a string?

Comment: @zaph I am not sure why I must convert the public key to a string. I tried sending the public key as its original type, and received an error telling me I must convert to "string" or "buffer". Can you clarify what you mean by reversing the encoding? Thank you

Comment: Notice: or "buffer". You need to study sockets, binary and string encodings (ASCII and unicode UTF-8).

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** exporting/importing keys using `exportKey()` and `importKey()`

**Why your conversion does not work**

Converting the key to a string using `str()` does not work, as you can see from the example below.

```
>>> k = RSA.generate(1024)
>>> pk = k.publickey()
>>> str(pk)
'<_RSAobj @0x10e518908 n(1024),e>'
```

As you can see from the example above, the function `str()` just returns the string `'<_RSAobj @0x10e518908 n(1024),e>'` which does not show the actual key.

**Converting the key object into a string**

A good way to convert the key into a string is to export it using a standard format, for example the well-known PEM format, as shown below.

```
>>> pkstring = pk.exportKey("PEM")
>>> pkstring
'-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC4SD0YSMWYAU27mFVKsHgtKWzM\n9jfvs2Xl+zCQpAHNtvYWTo6mnyWTwH4lGn7ulYdGx5gAJj6OlWg+CKoHXqPOh6e4\nP8DM97dM9QfP8d7el2ZCz1+5oMd8iQo+WPTM1qa5TMj9rZMpwAnSrS490LW6ZpTL\n7fChg3APljnspQ/7nQIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----'
```

Now, the string returned by `pk.exportKey("PEM")` corresponds to the *actual* key.

**Converting the string back to a key object**

This is also very easy, you can just type:

```
>>> importedpk = RSA.importKey(pkstring)
```

Now you can use the `encrypt` method with the `importedpk` key which has been converted from the string `pkstring`.

To prove you that `importedpk` has been loaded correctly, just type the following two commands on the python interpreter.

```
pk.encrypt("Hello", 12)
importedpk.encrypt("Hello", 12)
```

They should return the same output. In particular, if you type

```
pk.encrypt("Hello", 12) == importedpk.encrypt("Hello", 12)
```

the result should be

```
True
```

**How to fix your code**

In server code, replace

```
if c.send(str(public_key)):
  print "Public Key Sent"
```

with

```
if c.send(public_key.exportKey("PEM")):
  print "Public Key Sent"
```

In client code, replace

```
public_key = s.recv(1024)
```

with

```
public_key = RSA.importKey(s.recv(1024))
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by instead by pickling the `public_key` object using `cpickle` module aka `pickle.dumps(public_key)`. The pickled object is able to travel over the socket and be "unpickled" by the client on the other side!

Comment: This solution is _correct_ and I am glad that it solves your problem, but it is a bit like killing a mosquito using a cannon. First, because you need to import another module in order to apply it, and second because you are not just sending the public key over the connection, but you are sending much more data related to the object that you actually don't need, also introducing unnecessary overhead.
The solution I suggested in my answer just sends the key without any further unnecessary data.

Comment: In particular, if you run `pkstring = public_key.exportKey("PEM")` and `pkpickle = pickle.dumps(public_key)`, you will find out that `pkpickle` is definitely longer than `pkstring`, for example I have just typed `len(pkstring)` and `len(pkpickle)` on my interpreter, obtaining `271` and `379` respectively. Please also see my answer for an alternative solution, which just requires a single line change in your code for client and for server, and does not require to import an extra module since `importKey()` and `exportKey()` are still part of the pycrypto `RSA` module.